# Azure custom role: authorize role assignment for a specific set of roles

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a custom role in Azure that would allow Subscriptions "owners" to do quite everything but cancelling/renaming their own subscriptions or moving into another management group.

I would also like them to be able to grant right access to who they want (especially built-in "Contributor" role) but without allowing them to grant "Owner" right, otherwise my custom role could be tricked easily.

I ended up with the following custom role definition which is so far nice and working, apart from the role assignment of course:

```
{
  "Name": "MyCustomRole",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Role designed for Azure subscriptions ownership limitations",
  "Actions": [
    "*"
  ],
  "NotActions": [
    "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/subscriptions/write",
    "Microsoft.Subscription/cancel/action",
    "Microsoft.Subscription/rename/action"
  ],
  "DataActions": [],
  "NotDataActions": [],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/root.mg"
  ]
}
```

In the Azure documentation, the only operation I found for role assignment is `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`.

Is there any way to restrict that - to Contributor role assignment for instance - directly in the custom role?

Azure Policy might technically do the trick (not even sure), but since some operational/experts/whatever guys might end up as Owner, I do not want the policy engine to display "non-compliant" resources. It would lead customers to misunderstandings that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try Azure Policy, which you can apply on top of your IAM model. You can assign a policy on the Subscription or Management Group level, based on your governance structure.

Policy definition below will block EVERY request trying to assign "Owner" role with no exception. Built-in Owner role is represented by "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635", same GUID across all Azure tenants.

However Role assignments of other RBAC roles would still be possible. This should fullfill your use case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

```
{
  "policyType": "Custom",
  "mode": "All",
  "displayName": "DenyOwnerAssisgnment",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/roleDefinitionId",
          "contains": "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. Is it possible to define a scope policy hierarchy? By which I mean have a policy denying your requests on a subscription scope but allowing them inside specific resource groups?

Comment: Yes this should be possible. Please see my 2nd answer regarding Excluded Scopes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/assignment-structure

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge - no, you cannot be granular. you can only restrict a specific action.

ps. technically this is correct. but the policy usage above is really clever ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible when you assign a policy, so it's not part of the definition but assignment. You can assign policy on the subscription-level scope, and exclude resource groups. You can do that via "notScopes".

Please see Azure Policy docs for how to do this (chapter **Excluded scopes**)

> The scope of the assignment includes all child resource containers and
>   child resources. If a child resource container or child resource
>   shouldn't have the definition applied, each can be excluded from
>   evaluation by setting notScopes. This property is an array to enable
>   excluding one or more resource containers or resources from
>   evaluation. notScopes can be added or updated after creation of the
>   initial assignment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/assignment-structure

You can include excluded scopes in the portal when assigning Policy or through [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-4.2.0) by including `-NotScope` parameter.