# Is It possible to restrict the user to display the builtInRoles in roles drop down when assigning a role to new user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-policy

We have requirement where we need to create a role xxxx and assign to a user A. This user A can create a user but should assign only custom role xxxx to his users.

I Have created a custom role xxxx and in permissions I have excluded the Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignment (read, write and delete). This stop the user assigning the roles compltely, But my requirement is user A can assign only custom role to the user (Hide Buil in roles in the drop down)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can do this kind of logic into an azure policy ( roles will be showed into the drop down , but when you finalize the operation will get an error ) .

A similar thread [Azure custom role: authorize role assignment for a specific set of roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270885/azure-custom-role-authorize-role-assignment-for-a-specific-set-of-roles)